# How can I convert html.slim files to html or html.erb?

Tags: html, converters, erb, slim-lang

I need to convert the html.slim files in my Ruby on Rails application to html.erb. Is there any easy way to do it? I tried many options listed in Stack Overflow and other sites. But nothing worked for me. I found a converter http://slim2html.raving.systems/ and a html to slim converter http://html2slim.herokuapp.com/ . It is not of my use since it does not work the other way around. Should I have to do it manually? Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can!

First, make sure you have already installed `slim-rails`. You can install it by calling `gem install slim-rails`.

Then write something in the `input.html`

Finally, you open the terminal and call:

`` echo `slimrb input.html` > output.html ``

*NOTE*: it is `` ` ``, not `'` or `"`

Open file `output.html`, that's what you looking for!

Answer (score 28):

I just did it using [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io)

Start a new pen. Choosing Slim as your HTML Markdown language. Paste in your Slim - then click the `view compiled` button in your HTML pane.

You'll see the straight HTML version of your markup.

You can then copy that out.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that all the data you fill on Codepen is sent to their server. Make sure to not paste confidential data on Codepen or any other similar web tool. Happy Cyber Security Awareness Month. :)

Answer (score 4):

@duykhoa's answer is best and best for converting a whole file, but you can also use the inspector to see and copy the *compiled* HTML (CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome or right-click and then click on `inspect` to inspect an element).

Answer (score 4):

```
slimrb -e foo.html.slim foo.html.erb
```

so on my ubuntu/git bash console, this is what is do it , easily

```
mike@mike-PORTEGE-Z30t-A:~/workspace/demo$ slimrb -e app/views/layouts/_header.html.slim app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
```

and i get my new converted .erb file for .slim file.

Comment: The `-e` switch was exactly what I needed to keep function calls and the likes. Thanks! :)