# Convert html.slim views to html.erb - Rails, Slim, ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

Trying to **convert **.html.slim* views to **.html.erb*.** I've looked at these two questions:

- [How can I convert html.slim to html.erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277482/how-can-i-convert-html-slim-to-html-erb) - getting `uninitialized constant` when called from the console
- [How can I convert html.slim files to html or html.erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316036/how-can-i-convert-html-slim-files-to-html-or-html-erb) - parser hits a `NoMethodError: undefined method image_tag for nil:NilClass` when it comes across the first `= image_tag`. I am not using any variables inside my call, the image tag points to and *svg*

I think the latter solution would work best, if the good people of Stack Overflow can help me figure out the `image_tag` issue.

#### My code (as requested):

```
page data-id="foo-page"
  .container
    = image_tag 'bar.svg'
```

Comment: How can we help you figure out your `image_tag` issue unless you post your code? There's no guarantee anyone can reproduce your issue without using the same input.

Comment: @MarsAtomic well, I did mention that " I am not using any variables inside my call, the image tag points to and svg " . Here is my code: `= image_tag 'hello-mars-attomic.svg'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to avoid the unexpected code from Temple is to add: `-o disable_escape=true` for a total of:

`slimrb --rails -e -o disable_escape=true foo.html.slim > foo.html.erb`

This will work :-)

Answer (score 8):

As expected, the latter solution worked. The trick is to pass `-e` flag, letting the interpreter know that you're converting to `erb`. So the full command is:

```
 slimrb -e `foo.html.slim` > foo.html.erb
```

#### EDIT:

to make sure that the interperter omits unnecessary calls to `Temple::Utils.escape_html((...))` before variables, you can pass the `--rails` flag like so:

```
slimrb --rails -e `foo.html.slim` > foo.html.erb
```

Comment: the --rails flag didn't remove the Temple code for me.

Comment: Neither for me, it's still there

Answer (score 5):

I was using gitbash on windows,

and this worked for me,

```
slimrb -e foo.html.slim foo.html.erb
```