# How to convert slim to erb without wrapping code with escape_html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I'm converting multiple html.slim files to html.erb. After following plenty of brilliant advice and tips on stack overflow, I'm pretty much done, but I'm not happy with the html.erb code that is generated. I understand that it's not going to be perfect, but I'm getting an additional `Temple::Utils.escape_html((...))` around my links, as in:

`<%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((link_to "Jobs", jobs_path)) %>`

I finally came across [Dimitry_N's (Stack Overflow) answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837220/convert-html-slim-views-to-html-erb-rails-slim-erb), but even when I pass the `--rails` flag as he suggests, I still get the superfluous code.

I've come across one or two Regex options to delete the additional code *after* file is created, but I'm hoping to find something that expands on Dimitry's answer so that they're not inserted in the first place.

Has anyone experienced this or know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`escape_html` is [coming](https://github.com/judofyr/temple/blob/v0.9.1/lib/temple/filters/escapable.rb#L18) from *Temple*, which is part of the *Slim* engine [configuration](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/blob/v4.1.0/lib/slim/engine.rb#L33):

```rb
filter :Escapable
```

*Temple::Filters::Escapable* has a [`disable_escape`](https://github.com/judofyr/temple/blob/v0.9.1/lib/temple/filters/escapable.rb#L12) option. I made this while figuring it out:

```rb
class ERBConverter < Slim::Engine
  replace :StaticMerger, Temple::Filters::CodeMerger
  replace :Generator, Temple::Generators::ERB
  replace(:Escapable, :Escapable) { Temple::Filters::Escapable.new(disable_escape: true) }
end
```

```html
puts ERBConverter.new.call(File.read("test.html.slim"))

<div class="flex bg-red-500">
<%= link_to "link", link_path, class: "a" %>
</div>
```

But later noticed `--option` flag, and you can just pass it to `slimrb`:

```bash
$ slimrb -e -o disable_escape=true test.html.slim

<div class="flex bg-red-500">
<%= link_to "link", link_path, class: "a" %>
</div>
```

*https://rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#available-options*