# HTML.SLIM to HTML.ERB href reference

Tags: html, ruby, erb

Stuck with href when moving content from html.slim to html.erb

slim

```
a[href="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}"]
```

Tried few in options in .erb - none worked:

```
<a href="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}" class=...

<ahref="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}" class= ...

<a [href="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}"] class= ...

<a[href="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}"] class= ...

<a :href="#{service_url(id: @data['service_id'])}" class= ...
```

I tried converting the code using methods provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316036/how-can-i-convert-html-slim-files-to-html-or-html-erb) but I'm not getting any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<a href="<%= service_url(id: @data['service_id']) %>" class=...
```

The automatic string substitution that slim gives you (with the `#{var}` syntax) is not available in ERB, so you need to use explicit ERB output tags.

Comment: Thank @DannyB, that helped. There is another one I am struggling with: `type: t("element_names.#{@data['consultancy']}"))` . I tried:    `<%= type: t("element_names.<%=@data['consultancy']%>")%>` and `<% t("element_names.@data['consultancy']")%>` , but looks like it isn't the right way.

Comment: I suggest you read a little about slim and a little about ERB, it will eliminate most of the guesswork. I am guessing `type` is generating an HTML `<type>` tag when the slim is evaluated? In ERB, you explicitly write your HTML, and just use ERB tags when you want Embedded Ruby: `<type><%= t(...) %></type>`. See [this ERB tags SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erb-in-rails)